# Looping over files leads to infinte loop

Tags: bash

```
for LIBNAME in $OGRE_BUILD_DIR/sdk/lib/$CONFIG-iphoneos/libOgre*
do
    BASELIBNAME=`basename $LIBNAME`
    echo lipo $BASELIBNAME
    lipo $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphoneos/$BASELIBNAME -arch i386 $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphonesimulator/$BASELIBNAME -create -output $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG/$BASELIBNAME
done
```

When I run this in a script, it gets into an infinite loop - the first file in the search gets echoed over and over and over. If I `echo` in front of the call to `lipo $SDK_DIR...` then it does as expected loop through all the files.

I'm not familiar with bash, what's wrong?

Comment: Weird, can't quite figure this one out without being there to see it ;-) ! You can turn on the shell debugging (such as it is), with `set -vx` to see lines/blocks of code and variable values as they are executed. Maybe  you'll see something in that output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

So, what is the name of this script?  Did you call it `lipo`, also?  There's a very good chance that that your script is recursively calling itself.  The fact that it works correctly when you suppress the call to `lipo` in the loop tends to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, try running it in verbose mode (`-x`) as @shelter suggested and post the output (...of the first few iterations...).  You can add the `set` command to your script, or run your script as `sh -x /path/to/my_script`.